# How can i use safe-browsing application object to determine whether a url is reported as phishing site or malware site?

Tags: firefox-addon, dataprovider, malware, phishing, safe-browsing

Here is code snippet:

```
Components.classes['@mozilla.org/safebrowsing/application;1']
    .getService().wrappedJSObject.malwareWarden.listManager_
    .safeLookup(test_url, function(tableName){
        if (tableName == 'goog-phish-shavar' || tableNmae == 'goog-malware-shavar') {
            alert('This is reported by Google! ');
        };
});
```

It works fine, but I don't think it is the 'right' way...

What if user change the DataProvider?

Comment: Code reference: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/safebrowsing/content/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing any methods or properties of an XPCOM object using wrappedJSObject is a problem waiting to happen. Anything accessed via wrappedJSObject is considered "private" data and methods - potentially breaking in future releases. Try to avoid it.

The good news is the the "listManager" is itself a global XPCOM service. Access it directly using:

```
 var Cc = Components.classes;
 var Ci = Components.interfaces;
 var listManager = Cc["@mozilla.org/url-classifier/listmanager;1"].getService(Ci.nsIUrlListManager);
```

As for changing the data provider, it will take a fair amount of code changes to Firefox before that can happen. If it does, we would hopefully add some management methods to XPCOM as well.